# Nesting SQL statements?

Tags: mysql

I have a good idea of sql and nesting SQL statements but this one statement has REALLY stumped me right now. I'm currently studying for my database systems this weekend and this question came up:

What is the outcome?

```
select distinct T1.B
from T as T1
where not exists (
select * from T as T2
where not exists (
select * from T as T3
where T1.B = T3.B and T3.C = T2.C
)
)
```

with the data
You are given the following table T.

```
A B C
1 10 100
2 10 10
3 40 100
4 30 200
5 25 90
6 10 200
7 10 9
```

I would like to think I understand nesting but how would the statement :

```
select * from T as T3
where T1.B = T3.B and T3.C = T2.C
```

work? in that statement T hasn't been renamed to T1 yet? I thought thats how nesting works, do everything in the brackets first?

The outcome I thought also was going to be

```
10
40
30
25
```

but obviously this isnt an issue since I don't seem to get the question.

Comment: double not exist is one of the tough logic, easier get yourself lost later even when it was working. so it is hard to debug later. try to use simpler SQL

Comment: What is your question actually the outcome of the first query or how to achieve the result?

Comment: @SIDU it was a question off a past paper, but it is absolutely frying my brain!

Comment: In this case, the correlated subqueries do not get run first. (This differs from an inline view query, a subquery referenced as a rowsource in place of a table in the FROM clause.) In this case the outer query runs first. For each row accessed from T1, evaluate the condition in the WHERE clause. Evaluate the NOT EXISTS by executing the subquery. And again the same processing is performed. For each row accessed, evaluate the WHERE clause, evaluate the NOT EXISTS by executing the subquery. The values of the rows being examined by the outer queries is available to the inner *correlated* subquery.

Comment: double not exists only happens in exam papers, i did 100% correct in the uni, however never use it in my work