# How to perform arithmetic on a column defined on a SELECT statement

Tags: sql

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(MINUTE, j.start_time , j.end_time) as job_duration,
         (jtype.cost_per_minute * job_duration) as job_cost
```

All the joins and from statements are done it runs without error when there is no arithmetic to be done but with the multiplication it gives an error. Not sure what to do. Any help would be appreciated thanks in advance.

> Invalid column name 'job_duration'

Comment: Yup.  That is how SQL works.  You can use a subquery or CTE to define `job_duration`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

job_duration does not exist until the query gets executed you can do it by [nesting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34937413/nesting-sql-statements) into another sql clause or by doing this:

```
 SELECT DATEDIFF(MINUTE, j.start_time , j.end_time) AS job_duration, (jtype.cost_per_minute * DATEDIFF(MINUTE, j.start_time , j.end_time)) AS 'job_cost'
```

Comment: Ooops didn't see your fine answer, will delete mine

Answer (score 0):

Another way to write that statement:

```
;with _CTE as 
(
SELECT YourJobId, DATEDIFF(MINUTE, start_time , end_time) AS job_duration
from YourTableName 
)
Select jtype.cost_per_minute * _CTE.job_duration AS 'job_cost'
from YourTableName as jType
  inner join _CTE on jtype.YourJobId = _CTE.YourJobId
```

Comment: Sorry but I am new to SQL and could you please tell me what _CTE is? and why you used it in your statement? Thank you.

Comment: CTE stands for Common Table Expressions. It is like a temporary result (table) on server. Basically, I am calculating the job duration using the first select statement and the result is saved as a temporary table (which I called _CTE) and then I joined that result to your table. After the query is done, the CTE is cleared and removed from memory. The performance of CTE is good and it improves the readability of the query.

Comment: You can read more about CTE here: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766(v=sql.105).aspx